# facebook access token for offline_access - PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the status from facebook users, who connect to my app with offline_access and read_stream permissions.

All the processes will use subscription to get notification about new feeds, and then take access to status of the user, who changed it.

The code for subscription works great, I get all info as it should be, but the problem starts with second part - every time I try to access user status via

```
$objFacebook->api('/'USER_ID'/statuses?access_token=TOKEN', 'get', $params);
```

I get the exception:

> An access token is required to request this resource

I tried to set `access_token` which I got when connected to my website via facebook login, also tried to set the whole session in similar way as it is done here:

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => ... 
    [base_domain] => ...
    [expires] => 0
    [secret] => ...
    [session_key] => ...
    [sig] => ...
    [uid] => ...
)
```

but it didn't help. On the other side, when I copied my `access_token` generated via facebook developers (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) it works correctly, so it looks like my app generates an incorrect access token.

Do you have any idea where the problem can be?

To connect I use facebook-php-2.0 library.

Comment: does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852460/facebook-access-token ?

Comment: Not really, the problem is that I have access token stored in DB/file/etc. but is seems not to work with my api request.

Comment: are you storing your current access token or the user token as if i remember correctly you get a token from the user then when doing some thing you have to request a current token key using the saved offline user token

Comment: you should upgrade to 3.0 https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should upgrade to [version 3 of the PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). We made some changes to the cookie format and other things you can read about [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/). Version 2 will [stop working](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) on September 1st, so you'll need to upgrade soon anyways. Once you've done that, things should work for you.

P.S. You probably will want to use the "/posts" connection rather than than the "/statuses" connection of the [User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) as it will also give you any posts the user made that include attachments. The "/statuses" connection will only return text-only posts the user made. We'll update the documentation to clarify that.